# ABPersonRemoveImageData leaks even when released?

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks

Hi I am using this code to set a contact image. 
I am getting leaks in Instruments and it points to " ABPersonSetImageData(ref, cfdata, &error);" line.
I dont see the problem and i would love to get some help here.

thanks

shani

```
    if(person.state!=0){
        //set default image;
        NSString *n=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", person.category_en,@"_B"];
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:n];


        NSData *dataRef = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img); 
        CFDataRef cfdata = CFDataCreate(NULL, [dataRef bytes], [dataRef length]);


        ABPersonRemoveImageData(ref, &error); 
        ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &error);
        ABPersonSetImageData(ref, cfdata, &error);

        CFRelease(cfdata);

        //set default category name;
        ABRecordSetValue(ref, kABPersonJobTitleProperty, NSLocalizedString(person.category,@""), &error);
        //set notes to person
        ABRecordSetValue(ref, kABPersonNoteProperty,person.note, &error);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the bug of iOS SDK 4.2. I never encounter this problem before iOS SDK 4.2. But the instruments show me the leak about **ABPersonSetImageData()** at iOS SDK 4.2 final version. So, maybe next iOS SDK 4.3 will fix this problem.